# laravel forceDelete wont work on multiple

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I have this function:

```
public function delmultiplemessagesforce(Request $request){
  $messages = Message::whereIn('id', $request->input('ids'))->get();
  foreach($messages as $message){
    $message->parent()->forceDelete();
    $message->childs()->forceDelete();
    $message->forceDelete();
  }
}
```

it returns code `200` but will not actually delete data in database.

`Ajax`

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('.icheckboxdel').on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var ids = $(".panel-body input:checkbox:checked").map(function(){
                return $(this).val();
            }).get();

            $.ajax({
                url: '{{ route("delmultiplemessagesforce")}}',
                type: "POST",
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                },
                data: {'ids': ids},
                success:function(data) {
                  alert('successfully deleted.');
                  window.location.reload();
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

> Note: I have same function for `delete()` item and it works but for
>   `forceDelete()` it doesn't.

**Any idea?**

Comment: Show the errors you are facing.

Comment: @ManzurulHoqueRumi As I said I'm getting code 200 there is no error, just not deleting data from database.